# Julia - Very high-performance matrix computation -> efficient memory management

Tags: math, matrix, julia, numeric

I have a computationally involved question regarding matrix multiplication in Julia. Actually I started learning Julia today. Previously I have used Python, numpy etc. a lot.

However, I have a 6x6 matrix *A* which I want to multiply with an initial vector *x<sub>1</sub>*, that I already have and then add another vector *a<sub>1</sub>* to the product. Then I use the output vector *x<sub>2</sub>* of this as input for the same operation with the same matrix *A*, but different vector *a<sub>2</sub>* and so on.

That is:

0. Iteration: *x<sub>1</sub>*
1. Iteration: *x<sub>2</sub>* = *A* *x<sub>1</sub>*+*a<sub>1</sub>*
2. Iteration *x<sub>3</sub>* = *A* *x<sub>2</sub>*+*a<sub>2</sub>*
3. Iteration ...

The objects involved are very small, but the problem is, I want to do this operation a lot of times: on the order of ~10<sup>11</sup> to ~10<sup>13</sup> number of times. Additionally, I require an exceedingly high precision of the numeric values, far above that given by Float64.

I was able to write a straight-forward approach, which does what I want and in the precision I want. In good/ established python practise I have predefined my arrays and just fill them up with computed values as I go along. However, I have the feeling that I am bottlenecked by inefficient memory management, as the number of allocation probably shows.

Every now and then (say every 1000 iterations) I would like to save the vector *x<sub>i</sub>* of the current iteration to another array *m*, which is the output of the function with my results.

I thought it would be efficient to just replace the values of the vector *x* with the result of the computation of the *i*th iteration *A* *x*+*a<sub>i</sub>*. Apparently this inplace operation could be handled by the function `mul!` of the `LinearAlgebra` package, which uses BLAS to do `mul!(Y, A, B) -> Y`. I have also looked into the `StaticArrays` package, but I am not sure whether this would help.

I do not see any speedup of the computation or decrease of memory allocations. Can I optimize my code somehow? NOTE: for simplicity in this example I use the same vector *a* in each iteration.

```
using CSV
using DataFrames
using Arblib
using LinearAlgebra

setprecision(350) # this is required for the high accuracy

function compute() # global function wrapper, I thought this would be better
    dff = rand(BigFloat,(6,6)); # I would usually import a specific external matrix
    df2 = Matrix(dff)

    vecci = Array{BigFloat}([0,0,0,0,1e-21,1e-23]); # this will be my offset vector a
    x1 = Array{BigFloat}([0,0,0,0,1e-21,1e-23]); # this will be my input vector x0



    function fold(mat, x, a) # here it goes
        numevals = Int(1e6); #here I would put 1e11
 
        numsaves = 10^(Int(log10(numevals))-3) #takes three orders of magnitude less than numevals, this is the number of iterations I want to save in my array
        m = zeros(BigFloat,6, Int(numevals/numsaves)); # my output array where I store the x_i
        
        lastone = zeros(BigFloat,6);
        newone = zeros(BigFloat,6);

        m[1:6] .= x; # first iteration
        lastone .= x; # used as input for the computation

        for k in 1:(numevals-2)
            mul!(newone, mat, lastone); #replaces current newone with the result of matrix multiplication
            newone .+= a; #adds the offset vector
            lastone .= newone; # prepares for next iteration
            
            if mod(k,numsaves)==0 # every 1e3 iterations it stores in output array
                m[1+6*Int(k/numsaves):6+6*Int(k/numsaves)] .= newone
            end
            
        end
        return m
    end

    @time out2 = fold(df2, x1, vecci)

end

compute()
```

The output is e.g.

```
12.948946 seconds (204.00 M allocations: 11.399 GiB, 13.52% gc time)
6×1000 Matrix{BigFloat}:
 0.0      7.03814e+465  1.93614e+953  5.3262e+1440   1.4652e+1928   4.03066e+2415  1.10881e+2903  …  4.9002e+484980   1.34801e+485468  3.70828e+485955  1.02012e+486443  2.80629e+486930
 0.0      6.45989e+465  1.77707e+953  4.8886e+1440   1.34482e+1928  3.6995e+2415   1.01771e+2903     4.4976e+484980   1.23726e+485468  3.40361e+485955  9.3631e+486442   2.57572e+486930
 0.0      8.17893e+465  2.24997e+953  6.1895e+1440   1.70269e+1928  4.68398e+2415  1.28853e+2903     5.69445e+484980  1.5665e+485468   4.30935e+485955  1.18547e+486443  3.26115e+486930
 0.0      6.71808e+465  1.8481e+953   5.08399e+1440  1.39857e+1928  3.84737e+2415  1.05838e+2903     4.67736e+484980  1.28671e+485468  3.53965e+485955  9.73733e+486442  2.67867e+486930
 1.0e-21  7.55747e+465  2.07901e+953  5.7192e+1440   1.57331e+1928  4.32808e+2415  1.19062e+2903     5.26177e+484980  1.44748e+485468  3.98191e+485955  1.0954e+486443   3.01336e+486930
 1.0e-23  8.44558e+465  2.32332e+953  6.39129e+1440  1.7582e+1928   4.83669e+2415  1.33054e+2903  …  5.88011e+484980  1.61758e+485468  4.44984e+485955  1.22412e+486443  3.36747e+486930
```

EDIT:

Thanks to the comments I managed to update the code with type casting and MultiFloat package instead of BigFloat. This gives a speed increase of around 3x, but also a lot of accuracy is lost. But the number of allocations and required memory went down quite a bit, which is already a big improvement!

```
using CSV
using DataFrames
using MultiFloats
using LinearAlgebra
using Arblib

setprecision(350) # this is required for the high accuracy OF THE IMPORT ONLY

function compute() # global function wrapper, I thought this would be better
    dff = rand(Float64x5,(6,6)); # I would usually import a specific external matrix
    df1 = Array{Float64x5}(dff)
    df2 = Matrix(df1)

    

    vecci = Array{Float64x5}([0,0,0,0,1e-21,1e-23]); # this will be my offset vector a
    x1 = Array{Float64x5}([0,0,0,0,1e-21,1e-23]); # this will be my input vector x0


    function fold(mat::Matrix{MultiFloat{Float64, 5}}, x::Vector{MultiFloat{Float64, 5}}, a::Vector{MultiFloat{Float64, 5}}) # here it goes
        numevals = Int(1e6); #here I would put 1e11
 
        numsaves = 10^(Int(log10(numevals))-3) #takes three orders of magnitude less than numevals, this is the number of iterations I want to save in my array
        m = zeros(Float64x5,6, Int(numevals/numsaves)); # my output array where I store the x_i
        
        lastone = zeros(Float64x5,6);
        newone = zeros(Float64x5,6);

        m[1:6] .= x; # first iteration
        lastone .= x; # used as input for the computation

        for k in 1:(numevals-2)
            newone .= mat*lastone + a;
            lastone .= newone; # prepares for next iteration
            
            if mod(k,numsaves)==0 # every 1e3 iterations it stores in output array
                #print(newone)
                m[1+6*Int(k/numsaves):6+6*Int(k/numsaves)] .= newone
            end
            
        end
        return m
    end

    @time out2 = fold(df2, x1, vecci)

end

compute()
```

The output is now

```
2.898294 seconds (2.00 M allocations: 580.139 MiB, 4.80% gc time)
```

EDIT 2:

After a few tries and discussions with colleagues, I was able to reduce the number of allocations quite a bit by using static arrays. I have also paid attention to type casting and preallocation. However, this did not result in a speed increase over the second code example. Rather the code was 25% slower. I will stick to it, however, due to the much lower memory consumption.

Furthermore for my use case, I will probably try to do a convergence study to find the best compromise of accuracy and speed when using high(er)-precision floats. With regular floats, a single matrix multiplication and vector addition takes around 140ns, which is probably as fast as it gets in this case. Only if the precision is several times higher (say Float64x5), the operations take around 4µs, which is crazy.

I highly recommend the `TimerOutputs` package for finding bottlenecks in the code.

Comment: BigFloats are really slow, are you sure you cannot manage with something less, like `Float128` or `Float256`? It is likely that the performance is more limited by this than anything else. Furthermore, BLAS does not support bigfloats, so you are probably better off with something custom.

Comment: As @DNF said, using lower precision will make a big difference. This is why doing algorithmic tricks is important in these kinds of calculations. A relevant parameter in many numerical tricks is the condition number of the matrix `A`. Do we know something about it? Or any other special properties of `A`? (did you think about doing calculation in basis where `A` diagonal?)

Comment: There is a package https://github.com/dzhang314/MultiFloats.jl which could be useful for multi precision floats.

Comment: Wow thank you for getting back to me so fast! I tried using the multifloat package, with the float64x5 datatype. This gave me already a big performance boost. However, I sacrifice accuracy - which admittedly I did not need to the extent I originally posted. Also I need more speed increase. I will update the question with what I find.

Answer (score 1):

Your code just returns a bunch of NaNs, but if I reduce the interval between saves, I can tell that they return the same values before going to NaN.

Bottom line is that I don't think you can improve performance much as long as you use MultiFloats. The following code reduces allocations very significantly, but improves speed only marginally. I tried StaticArrays, which made it go slower, and I tried Octavian.jl/LoopVectorization.jl, which does not work well with MultiFloats. Multplying two `Float64x5` takes approximately 32ns on my laptop, and a 6x6 matrix-vector product takes approximately 6^2 times as long. There is apparently no parallel speedup, no simd effect, no multi-threading you can exploit. Basically, you need a higher precision float which is simd friendly, I 'm not aware of any.

But I have improved your code a bit. Comments:

- `dff` is a matrix. I don't know why you create `df1` and `df2`, they seem redundant.
- `Float64x5(1e-23)` is not accurate, since there is precision loss before the conversion. `Float64x5("1e-23")` avoids this problem.
- I made `fold` more generic, it will now accept different array types and elements. (Also, I don't like nested functions, so I moved it out.)
- Use integer arithmetic instead of converting floats to Int, e.g. `div(a, b)` instead of `Int(a/b)`. And write `10^6` instead of `Int(1e6)`.
- When indexing into the matrix `m`, use matrix indexing instead of the awkward linear indexing.
- use `mul!` to avoid allocations.
- The line `lastone, newone = newone, lastone` switches the two vectors at zero cost, no need to copy data over.

...

```
function compute()
    dff = rand(Float64x5, 6, 6)
    vecci = Float64x5.(["0", "0", "0", "0", "1e-21", "1e-23"])
    x1 = copy(vecci) # this will be my input vector x0
    return fold(dff, x1, vecci)
end

function fold(mat::AbstractMatrix{T}, x::AbstractVector{T}, a::AbstractVector{T}) where {T<:Number}
    numevals = 10^6
    saveinterval = 1000
    numsaves = div(numevals, saveinterval)
    m = zeros(T, length(a), numsaves)
       
    lastone = copy(x)
    newone = zero(x)
    m[:, 1] .= x
    
    for k in 1:(numevals-2)
        # >95% of the time is spent on the next two lines, though they have zero allocations.
        mul!(newone, mat, lastone)
        newone .+= a
        (d, r) = divrem(k, saveinterval)
        if r == 0
            m[:, d+1] .= newone
        end
        lastone, newone = newone, lastone # prepares for next iteration
    end
    return m
end
```

Comment: Dear DNF, thank you for your helpful comments! Sorry for the long answer time, I was really busy. You're right the code prints out NaNs (in the end), but the reason is the large numbers that come out of multiplying a random matrix with the vector that many times. The external matrix I put in in my application does not have this problem and the numbers stay bounded.

Comment: I am glad you could improve my code, which I will try to implement as good/ efficient practise in my future coding. Thanks a lot for that!
However, to solve the problem of high efficiency, I am currently looking into other programming languages with other handling of numerics to maybe gain more computation speed.